# safe malloc/realloc: wrapping the call into a macro?

Tags: c, macros, malloc

I would like to wrap my calls to malloc/realloc into a macro that would stop the program if the method returns NULL

can I safely use the following macro?

```
#define SAFEMALLOC(SIZEOF) (malloc(SIZEOF) || (void*)(fprintf(stderr,"[%s:%d]Out of memory(%d bytes)\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,SIZEOF),exit(EXIT_FAILURE),0))
char* p=(char*)SAFEMALLOC(10);
```

it compiles, it works here with `SAFEMALLOC(1UL)` and `SAFEMALLOC(-1UL)` but is it a safe way to do this?

Comment: Why a macro, why not a function? That way you could actually get the "expression" to return a useful result.

Comment: Note that `SIZEOF` is evaluated twice when the call fails (not a disaster since the program exits, but still...).

Comment: casting the result wont make it any safer, though...

Comment: these are not my sources, I would like to avoid to create some new files (memory.c, memory.h) and I know the author want to avoid some calls to other functions (micro-optimization for a scientific C program)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's broken.

It seems to assume that the boolean or operator `||` returns its argument if it's deemed true, that's not how it works.

C's boolean operators always generate `1` or `0` as integers, they do *not* generate any of the input values.

Comment: `true` and `false` are macros in C99 that you can choose to include with `stdbool.h`. The result of `||` is still an `int` in C99.

Answer (score 14):

```
static void* safe_malloc(size_t n, unsigned long line)
{
    void* p = malloc(n);
    if (!p)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[%s:%ul]Out of memory(%ul bytes)\n",
                __FILE__, line, (unsigned long)n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}
#define SAFEMALLOC(n) safe_malloc(n, __LINE__)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using your macro:

```
#define SAFEMALLOC(SIZEOF) (malloc(SIZEOF) || (void*)(fprintf(stderr,"[%s:%d]Out of memory(%d bytes)\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,SIZEOF),exit(EXIT_FAILURE),0))

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *p = SAFEMALLOC(10);
    char *q = SAFEMALLOC(2000);

    printf("p = %p, q = %p\n", p, q);

    // Leak!
    return 0;
}
```

Warnings (should be a clue):

```
weird.c:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
weird.c:8: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
weird.c:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
weird.c:9: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Output:

```
p = 0x1, q = 0x1
```

In summary, no, it's not very safe! Writing a function would probably be less error prone.

Comment: i would cast to (char*) . But now I don't understand why p and q returns 0x1 ! That's the same address/pointer isn't it ? :-)

Comment: @Pierre: No, you *shouldn't* cast to `char*`; that would hide the warning that tells you that something is wrong!

Comment: @Pierre "But now I don't understand why p and q returns 0x1 ! " -- That's because you haven't done even the most rudimentary work to understand the language you're programming in. The value of (x || y) is always either 0 or 1.

Comment: @Pierre As for casts, good programmers treat them like X-rays or antibiotics ... to be used only if you absolutely must.